# Issues configuring CUPS print server for Ubuntu Server 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, print-server, cups

I have a 9.10 Ubuntu Server installed and I want to make it a print server and am trying to get access to the cups browser admin page from a windows client machine.  I installed cups:

```
sudo apt-get install cups
```

then I edited the /etc/cups/cupsd.conf file and tried several different listen cominbations:

```
Listen 192.168.1.109:631 #ip my router gives it3
Listen /var/run/cups/cups.sock #already in conf file
Listen fileserver:631 #hostname of server
Port 631 #listen for all incoming requests on 631?
```

samba is also installed (which I think is necessary to share the printer out?

and finally I added my user to the lpadmin group:

```
sudo adduser tone lpadmin
```

but when I try to navigate any of the following I get 403 forbidden

```
http://fileserver:631/admin
http://fileserver:631
http://192.168.1.109:631/admin
http://192.168.1.109:631
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a sample on the internet somewhere - had to make some changes to my config file:

```
# Only listen for connections from the local machine.
#Listen localhost:631
Listen *:631
Listen /var/run/cups/cups.sock

# Show shared printers on the local network.
Browsing On
BrowseOrder allow,deny
BrowseAllow all
BrowseAddress @LOCAL

# Default authentication type, when authentication is required...
DefaultAuthType Basic

# Restrict access to the server...
<Location />
  Order allow,deny
  Allow localhost
  Allow @LOCAL
</Location>

# Restrict access to the admin pages...
<Location /admin>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow @LOCAL
</Location>

# Restrict access to configuration files...
<Location /admin/conf>
  AuthType Default
  Require user @SYSTEM
  Order allow,deny
  Allow @LOCAL
</Location>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might find the answer in the logs

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/cups/{access,error}_log
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Listen *:631
```

Comment: this partially solved my issue, had to change a few others things as well

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure CUPS allows Admin / web access from localhost only by default.  If you're not on the same computer as CUPS, you may need to add
`Allow from 192.168.1.1/24`
to your [cupsd.conf <Location>](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.4/policies.html) sections.